# Are Burmese cats more prone to diabetes than other breeds?

Tags: cats, health, diabetes, burmese

I have a Burmese cat who was diagnosed with diabetes almost 10 years ago.  Through twice daily insulin injections and a controlled diet, he is now almost 16 years old.

I have been told that Burmese cats are more prone to diabetes than other breeds.

Is there any evidence to support this claim?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a study at the University of Queensland
[Over representation of Burmese cats with diabetes mellitus.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9247686) Rand, et al:

> Burmese cats were significantly over represented among cats with diabetes mellitus. Irrespective of breed, the risk of diabetes in the study population increased with age.

So, there's definitely evidence of it.

Comment: Coincidental that the study was done on cats in Queensland which is where I live.